# Two Files with the Same Name Under the Same Folder

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I have two files with the same name under the same folder. A file name is different between console and window explorer.

I used my software copy a file from somewhere else and rename it as **dxr.jpg**. The file did get copied to the **Downloads** folder, but its name remained as **Penguins.jpg**. The file's name appears as **dxr.jpg** in cmd console, but **Penguins.jpg** in window explorer. Then, I copied and pasted it under same foler which is **Downloads**. Then, renamed it as **Penguins.jpg**. Worked!! Two files with same name.

Using this function:

```
BOOL WINAPI CopyFile(
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpExistingFileName,
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpNewFileName,
  _In_  BOOL bFailIfExists
);
```

NOTE: the two files' name appear the same in window explorer, but, in cmd console, they are different.

I restarted my computer. The situation did not change. Anyone can tell me the reason. I am using windows 7 professional 64 bits.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, and as such is not suitable for this site.

Comment: "I used my software copy a file" - what software? Do you have the code you used?

Comment: @psych Looks like old MFC copy function does not compatible with new OS.

Comment: The Downloads folder is a *virtual* shell folder.  It shows a combination of your own Downloads folder and the c:\users\public\download folder.  So having two files with the same name is not impossible.

Comment: @HansPassant In addition to that, if I use that function copy images from Shell folder like **Libraries\Pictures** . There gonna be an renaming issue too.

Comment: Explorer can be told to show files with a name different from cmd. That's how Windows works in languages other than English. The file is called "Calculator.lnk" but in German, it shows up as "Rechner".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual shell folder is sort of different from others.

Answer (score 1):

MFC CopyFile() has a tiny issue for copying from virtual shell folders like **Libraries\Pictures**. .Net function might work.

Comment: `CopyFile` is not part of MFC. It is a Win32 API function. It works just fine.

Comment: If I copy from sample picture, the name does not get changed. The file name is different between console and window explorer

Comment: Copy from other location just works fine

Comment: I don't doubt you. But `CopyFile` works. It behaves as designed.